# Gaussian Distribution + Hash Tables

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hashtable, hash, variable-assignment

I had a weird idea about a hashing function. The problem statement is

> You are storing id-numbers of 162
>   students in a class obtaining n marks
>   out of 300 in a course (for each n=0,
>   1, 2, ... 300) in a hash table. Devise
>   the simplest and least collision prone
>   hash function for this such that the
>   wasted memory cells also are minimum.
>   Here, a collision is when two students
>   scoring n<sub>1</sub> and
>   n<sub>2</sub> get the same slot in the
>   hash table.

One solution can be to use h(n) = (n*5 + 7) % 163 along with chaining. There can be at most 162 distinct marks.

**EDIT** There can be several standard ways to do this. But I'd like to try my idea and check it (maybe mathematically). It just might have lesser collisions with lesser memory.

---

Now, here's the idea I had. I can assume distribution of marks to be [gaussian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution). So, there are more people near the average score and lesser at the extremes.

So, I can have a hash function something like this:

> h(n) = 0   (if n<100 || n>200)
>   h(n) = 1   (if 100<=n<125 || 175<=n<200)
>   h(n) = 2   (if 125<=n<140 || 160<=n<175)
>   h(n) = 3   (if 140<=n<160)

For some such conditions (say, k), the hash table will have the least number of collisions and the least amount of space occupied.

Now, this is just a guess.Does something like this make sense?Is there a way to prove this? Or am I wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing manually here is called in image processing [histogram equalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization). I think it makes absolutely sense, because you make sure that statistically all slots are used with the same probability, and so you're minimizing collisions.

Comment: Can you give me a reference to some paper/article that describes the math behind it?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Mis-read the question, voting 'delete' doesn't seem to do anything on SO.

Answer (score 0):

If your variable is normally distributed, why not transform it using the normal [CDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function)? The result would be uniformly distributed between 0 and 1 and would naturally be a good key into your hash table.

Comment: In order to compute the CDF for a value n, you need to do a lot of computation (binary search on the sorted array of scores comes to mind).  Or you could store the CDF in a hash table indexed by n...

Answer (score 0):

Doing histogram_equalization and the like can get pretty expensive.  You might consider other standard ways of reducing [hash collisions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_collision) or their effects, like [cuckoo hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckoo_hashing) or [hopscotch hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopscotch_hashing).

Comment: True, but I'd like to explore this possibility. And maybe come up with some math that describes it. (Edited question to reflect this)